# How to filter products in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Good day,

i am quite a newbie at react and i am making my first ecommerce website. My question is: How do i filter my products by size? I can't really think of the logic. Thank you in advance for your answers. I have tried to use Redux also, but had no succes it gave me the following error: ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

code product Cards:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {Library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import {faShoppingBasket} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { listProduct, Filterproducts } from '../../actions/productActions'



function Product(props){
    //default value is an array, because we've got data in an array 
    const [qty,setQty] = useState(1)
    const productList = useSelector(state=>state.productList)
    const{products,loading,error}=productList
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    // handlefilter

  

    useEffect(()=> {
        dispatch(listProduct())
       


  

    }, [])

    // handle cart adding
    const handleAddToCart = ()=> {
        props.history.push('/cart/' + props.match.params.id +  "?qty" +qty)
    }


  


   
    return( 
        // Check the loading before rendering products
        loading? <div><h1 className="load">loading...</h1></div> : 
        error?<div>{error}</div>:
           <ul className="products">
               
            {products.map(product=> (
        
            <li key={product.id} className="product"> 
             <Link to={"/product/" + product.id}><div className="img" style={{background: `url(${product.img})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}></div></Link>
                   {/* LOOK OUT FOR TYPOS IN ROUTIING  dont put':' after /, this only applies
                   when routing because the ": " implies for a parameter
                   In this case you can directly access product.id  */}
               <Link to={"/product/" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></Link> 
                <p> <small>€</small>{product.price}</p>
                <div>size: {product.size}</div>
              
                {product.qty > 0 ? <div><button onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to cart</button>  <div>{product.qty} left</div></div> : <div>out of stock</div> }   
               
             
                
                </li> 
                )
                
                )}
   
                 </ul>
                 
       
    
    )
}
export default Product
```

code ProductActions:

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import {
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, 
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
    FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_PRICE,
    FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE} from '../constants/productConstants'



const listProduct = () => async(dispatch)=> {
    
        try{
            dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST})
            fetch('http://localhost:5000/')
            .then(res=> res.json())
            .then(data=> dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload:data}) )
           
        }
        catch(error){
            dispatch({type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload:error.message})
        }
   
  
  
}
// DETAILSPRODUCT
//we need to have a server in order to display the products
//it should get another link which contains the id of the product
const detailsProduct = (productId) => async(dispatch) => {
    try{
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId});
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/' + productId)
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=> dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload:data}) )
    }
    catch(error){
        dispatch({type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, payload: error.message})
    }
}

// Filter products
const Filterproducts = (products,size) => (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch({
        type:FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
        payload: {
            size:size,
            items:size === '' ? products : products.filter(a=> a.indexOf(size.toUpperCase()) >= 0)
        }
    })
}


export { listProduct, detailsProduct, Filterproducts }
```

code productReducers:

```
//two params are being accepted in the reducer func
    //* state 

import { 
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE,
    FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_PRICE } from "../constants/productConstants";

    //*action
function producListReducer(state = {products: [], filteredItems: [], size: ''}, action){
    
    switch (action.type){
        // case is like the if statement
        //getting product
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{loading: true};
            // when products are loaded
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, products: action.payload};
            //when err occurs
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return{loading: false, error: action.payload};
        case FILTER_PRODUCTS_BY_SIZE:
                return{...state, filteredItems: action.payload.items, size: action.payload.size}
        default:
                return state
    }
}

function productDetailsReducer(state = {product: {}}, action){
    
    switch (action.type){
        // case is like the if statement
        //getting product
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return{loading: true};
            // when products are loaded
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            return{loading:false, product: action.payload};
            //when err occurs
        case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return{loading: false, error: action.payload};
        default:
                return state
    }
}







export { producListReducer,productDetailsReducer }
```

Comment: format and indent your code correctly

Comment: The code you have posted so far is mostly irrelevant. The logic of filtering is pretty much straightforward: within `products.map(product => ..` use `if()`-statement to return JSX for valid items and `null`/`false`/`undefined` for those to be ignored.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thank you

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov i kept trying with redux, but i found it to be too complex. And i never thought of another way, so thank you for opening my eyes.

Comment: Redux is a tool for global state management to exchange the data between multiple scattered components you may (or may not) use that for filtering purposes (e.g. to store filtering criteria if one is passed from within some other component), however it cannot solve your specific *filtering* task directly.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov could you please give me an example of how you would write the code?

Comment: If you are new to React I suggest not using Redux until you develop a better understanding of what and how React functions and what the limits are. Then when you start hitting those limits you can consider alternative libraries. Like the Redux FAQ states: *"In general, use Redux when you have reasonable amounts of data changing over time, you need a single source of truth, and you find that approaches like keeping everything in a top-level React component's state are no longer sufficient."* - [Redux - FAQ - When should I use Redux?](https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux)

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you are trying to access the key "items" of an inexisting object. The only you are doing this in the posted code is in the productReducers, so I recomment you to check the function "Filterproducts" where you return the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Got the filter function working, but i dont know how to apply it.

The Searchbar Component:

```
import React from 'react'


// Function Searchbar 
//Looks for products 

function Search(props){

   
    return(
     <input 
     type="search"
     className="search"
     placeholder={props.placeholder}
     onChange={props.handleInput}/>
    )
}

export default Search
```

The product Component:

return(
// Check the loading before rendering products
loading? loading... :
error?{error}:

```
    {products.map(product=> (
    
        

    <li key={product.id} className="product"> 
     <Link to={"/product/" + product.id}><div className="img" style={{background: `url(${product.img})`, backgroundSize: 'cover'}}></div></Link>
           {/* LOOK OUT FOR TYPOS IN ROUTIING  dont put':' after /, this only applies
           when routing because the ": " implies for a parameter
           In this case you can directly access product.id  */}
       <Link to={"/product/" +  product.id}><h1>{product.name}</h1></Link> 
        <p> <small>€</small>{product.price}</p>
        <div>size: {product.size}</div>
      
        {product.qty > 0 ? <div><button onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to cart</button>  <div>{product.qty} left</div></div> : <div>out of stock</div> }   
       
     
        
        </li> 
        )
        
        )}

         </ul>
```

)

The Searchbar Functions in Store.js:

```
import React,{Component, useState} from 'react'
import Product from '../components/product'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import Footer from '../components/footer'
import Searchbar from '../components/searchbar'
import Filter from '../components/filter'


class Store extends Component{
   
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            SearchProduct: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=>this.setState({products:data}) )
       
    }
   
   render(){
       let filteredProducts = this.state.products.filter((product)=> {
            return product.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.SearchProduct.toLowerCase())
       })
    return (
        
        <div>
        <Nav/>
        <div className="store">

           
            <div className="title">
                <h1>Store</h1>
            </div>
            <aside>
                <Searchbar 
                placeholder="Search" 
                handleInput={(e)=> {
                   
                    this.setState({SearchProduct: e.target.value})
                }
                 
                } 
                />
                
                <ul>
                    <h2>Categories</h2>
                    <li>Women</li>
                    <li>Men</li>
                    <li>Clothing</li>
                    <li>Equipment</li>
                 
                </ul>
            </aside>
           
           <Filter/>
            
            <Product filter={filteredProducts}/>
            
         
           
        </div>
        <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
   }
   
}

export default Store
```